# Deriving tensor in Euler's equations for rigid body rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

The answer to [physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104513](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/104513/derivation-of-eulers-equations-for-rigid-body-rotation) gives the following derivation of tensor $I$:

$\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} I &= \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} (E\,I_{\text{body}}\,E^\top) \\
&= \frac{\text{d}E}{\text{d}t}\,I_{\text{body}}\,E^\top + E\,I_{\text{body}}\,\frac{\text{d}E}{\text{d}t}^\top \\
&= ([\omega]_\times\,E)\,I_{\text{body}}\,E^\top + E\,I_{\text{body}}\,([\omega]_\times\,E)^\top \\
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} I&= [\omega]_\times\,I_{\text{body}} + I_{\text{body}}\,[\omega]_\times
\end{align}$

But, I want to see the derivation happens element-by-element according to the definition of a tensor as I attempted below.

$\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(\begin{bmatrix}
  I_{1,1} & I_{1,2} & I_{1,3} \\
  I_{2,1} & I_{2,2} & I_{2,3} \\
  I_{3,1} & I_{3,2} & I_{3,3} \\
\end{bmatrix}\right) &= \begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\text{d}\,I_{1,1}}{\text{d}t} & \frac{\text{d}\,I_{1,2}}{\text{d}t} & \frac{\text{d}\,I_{1,3}}{\text{d}t} \\
  \frac{\text{d}\,I_{2,1}}{\text{d}t} & \frac{\text{d}\,I_{2,2}}{\text{d}t} & \frac{\text{d}\,I_{2,3}}{\text{d}t} \\
  \frac{\text{d}\,I_{3,1}}{\text{d}t} & \frac{\text{d}\,I_{3,2}}{\text{d}t} & \frac{\text{d}\,I_{3,3}}{\text{d}t} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$

Then, I calculated the above one as follows:
$\begin{align}
\frac{\text{d}I_{i,j}}{\text{d}t} &= \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(\sum_p m_p\,\left(\delta_{i,j} \sum_k r_k^2 - r_i\,r_j\right)\right) \\
&= \sum_p m_p \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,\left(\delta_{i,j} \sum_k r_{p,k}^2 \right) - \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,(r_{p,i}\,r_{p,j}) \\
&= \sum_p m_p \delta_{i,j} \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\, \left(\sum_k r_{p,k}^2\right) - \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,(r_{p,i}\,r_{p,j}) \\
&= \sum_p m_p \delta_{i,j} \sum_k \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,(r_{p,k}^2) - \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,(r_{p,i}\,r_{p,j}) \\
&= \sum_p m_p \delta_{i,j} \sum_k \frac{\text{d}\,r_{p,k}^2}{\text{d}r_{p,k}}\frac{\text{d}\,r_{p,k}}{\text{d}t} - \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,(r_{p,i}\,r_{p,j}) \\
&= \sum_p m_p \delta_{i,j} \sum_k 2\,r_{p,k}\,\omega_k - (\omega_i\,r_{p,j} + r_{p,i}\,\omega_j) \\
\frac{\text{d}\text{I}_{i,j}}{\text{d}t} &= \sum_p m_p \begin{bmatrix}
2\,r_{p,2}\,\omega_2 + 2\,r_{p,3}\,\omega_3 & -(r_{p,1}\,\omega_2 + r_{p,2}\,\omega_1) & -(r_{p,1}\,\omega_3 + r_{p,3}\,\omega_1) \\
-(r_{p,2}\,\omega_1 + r_{p,1}\,\omega_2) & 2\,r_{p,1}\,\omega_1 + 2\,r_{p,3}\,\omega_3 & -(r_{p,2}\,\omega_3 + r_{p,3}\,\omega_2) \\
-(r_{p,3}\,\omega_1 + r_{p,1}\,\omega_3) & -(r_{p,3}\,\omega_2 + r_{p,2}\,\omega_3) & 2\,r_{p,1}\omega_1 + 2\,r_{p,2}\,\omega_2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$

But, after trying some factorizations, I can't seem to get to the following:

$[\omega]_\times\,I_{\text{body}} + I_{\text{body}}\,[\omega]_\times$
$= \sum_p m_p \left( \begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\omega_3 & \omega_2 \\
\omega_3 & 0 & -\omega_1 \\
-\omega_2 & \omega_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
r_{p,2}^2 + r_{p,3}^2 & -r_{p,1} r_{p,2} & -r_{p,1} r_{p,3} \\
-r_{p,2} r_{p,1} & r_{p,1}^2 + r_{p,3}^2 & -r_{p,2} r_{p,3} \\
-r_{p,3} r_{p,1} & -r_{p,3} r_{p,2} & r_{p,1}^2 + r_{p,2}^2
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
r_{p,2}^2 + r_{p,3}^2 & -r_{p,1} r_{p,2} & -r_{p,1} r_{p,3} \\
-r_{p,2} r_{p,1} & r_{p,1}^2 + r_{p,3}^2 & -r_{p,2} r_{p,3} \\
-r_{p,3} r_{p,1} & -r_{p,3} r_{p,2} & r_{p,1}^2 + r_{p,2}^2
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -\omega_3 & \omega_2 \\
\omega_3 & 0 & -\omega_1 \\
-\omega_2 & \omega_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right)$
$= \sum_p m_p \left( \begin{bmatrix}
r_{p,1}\,r_{p,2}\,\omega_3 - r_{p,1}\,r_{p,3}\,\omega_2 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
-r_{p,1}\,r_{p,2}\,\omega_3 + r_{p,1}\,r_{p,3}\,\omega_2 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix} \right)$
$= \sum_p m_p \begin{bmatrix}
0 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix} \ne \sum_p m_p \begin{bmatrix}
2\,r_{p,2}\,\omega_2 + 2\,r_{p,3}\,\omega_3 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}$

So, I should have made a mistake in the differentiation. But, where? And, how to proceed?

Or, is it because the definition of tensor cannot be used in performing the derivation? Why?

Comment: Hint: Use the vector form of the [parallel axis theorem](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/111081/392) $$I = I_{cm} - [\vec{r}]\times [\vec{r}]\times $$ and note that your big matrix of $[ r_{p,2}^2 + \ldots]$ is really $[r_p]\times$.

Comment: Title should be deriving the _rate of change_ of the inertia tensor.

Comment: Funny how MIT just glosses over this part of the derivation in http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec28.pdf

Comment: By your hint, should I have started my derivation from the following? $\frac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}t} = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} (I_{\text{CM}} - [\vec{r}_p]_\times[\vec{r}_p]_\times) = \frac{\text{d}I_{\text{CM}}}{\text{d}t}  - \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} ([\vec{r}_p]_\times[\vec{r}_p]_\times)$

Comment: [Renewed] By your hint, should I have started my derivation from the following? $\frac{\text{d}I}{\text{d}t} = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} (I_{\text{CM}} - [\vec{r}_p]_\times[\vec{r}_p]_\times) = \frac{\text{d}I_{\text{CM}}}{\text{d}t}  - \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} ([\vec{r}_p]_\times[\vec{r}_p]_\times) = \frac{\text{d}I_{\text{CM}}}{\text{d}t}  - (\frac{\text{d}[\vec{r}_p]_\times}{\text{d}t}[\vec{r}_p]_\times + [\vec{r}_p]_\times \frac{\text{d}[\vec{r}_p]_\times}{\text{d}t})$

Comment: On paper I found the following: $\frac{\text{d}I_{\text{CM}}}{\text{d}t} - \left(\frac{\text{d}[\vec{r}_p]_\times}{\text{d}t} [\vec{r}_p]_\times + [\vec{r}_p]_\times \frac{\text{d}[\vec{r}_p]_\times}{\text{d}t} \right) = \begin{bmatrix} 4\,r_2\,\omega_2 + 4\,r_3\,\omega_3 & -2(r_1\,\omega_2 + r_2\,\omega_1) & -2(r_1\,\omega_3 + r_3\,\omega_1) \\
-2(r_2\,\omega_1 + r_1\,\omega_2) & 4\,r_1\,\omega_1 + 4\,r_3\,\omega_3 & -2(r_2\,\omega_3 + r_3\,\omega_2) \\
-2(r_3\,\omega_1 + r_1\,\omega_3) & -2(r_3\,\omega_2 + r_2\,\omega_3) & 4\,r_1\omega_1 + 4\,r_2\,\omega_2
\end{bmatrix}$ I don't get it...

Comment: Actually each infinitestimal mass does not have a mass moment of inertia so you have $${\rm d}I = -{\rm d}m [\vec{r}\times][\vec{r}\times]$$ as a starting point, and integrate over the volume.

Comment: But, by integrating, I cannot give rise to the term $\omega$. So, how could I arrive at the following then when finding the rate of change of tensor $I$ element-by-element? $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t} I = [\omega]_\times\,I_{\text{body}} + I_{\text{body}}\,[\omega]_\times$

Comment: The $\omega$ comes from [vector differentiation on moving coordinate frame](http://www.gcm.ac.in/downloads/elearning/classical_mechanics.pdf).